# How can I comment code with a command in Vim

Tags: ide

In various editors one can mark a block of code and with a shortcut, comment it right away. Is there a possible way to do it in Vim without an extra plugin? If not, which plugin or script would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way that I found is using [tpope's vim-commentary plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary). You're able to use the `ctrl+v I#` mentioned in the question linked to in the comment to the OP, but this will automatically work with different comment types with different languages.

Answer (score 0):

From my answer [over here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/154/153):

> I use [scrooloose/nerdcommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) for this.
>
> With this plugin you can visual select your lines and hit
> <kbd>leader</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to toggle comments. Depending on the
> file type it will use different symbols for commenting.