# How can I change/delete comments easily?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions, comments, plugin-vim-commentary, plugin-nerdcommenter

For commenting and uncommenting I now use the [vim-commentary plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary), also the [NERD commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) can be used as mentioned in:
[How to comment out a set of lines which are selected in visual mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/130/how-to-comment-out-a-set-of-lines-which-are-selected-in-visual-mode/154#154)

I would like to know if there is an easy combination to change comments, for example like <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> or delete the comments like 
<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>. Note that this does not work (for as far as I could find) with the vim-commentary or NERD commenter plugins.

Comment: [This plugin](https://github.com/thinca/vim-textobj-comment) provides text objects for comments. Note that I don't use it anymore and I don't remember the reason why so it might be a bit buggy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is a text-object representing a comment. See [`:h text-objects`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#text-objects) for more information about text-objects.

By default Vim doesn't contains text-objects representing comments but the [vim-textobj-comment](https://github.com/thinca/vim-textobj-comment) implements this feature. Once you've got it installed you'll be able to access comments with `ic` and `ac`.

Additionally, if this plugin isn't exactly what you want it is possible to define your own text-objects *(it's fun to do and a good occasion to learn new stuff)*. To do so you can have a look [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects).

Comment: [Commentary.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) also provides the `gc` text object. e.g. `dgc`

Comment: @PeterRincker: I've never used Commentary.vim but from reading the readme I'm not sure `gc` is the same thing: is it possible for example to do something like `vgc` to visually select the content of a comment?

Comment: Commentary.vim does not provide a visual mode mapping for `gc`. It only provides an operator pending mode mapping. I pretty much only use if for toggling a comment block via: `gcgc`

Comment: That sounds pretty useful. Actually I created this answer because I suggested vim-textobj-comment in the comments of the question and OP said it was what he wanted but maybe you should also add an answer with commentary.vim if it fills the needs of the question.

Answer (score 3):

[Commentary.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) provides the `gc` text object for comments. You can use `dgc` for example to delete a comment block. I find that my most common usage is `gcgc` to uncomment a comment block.

Note: Commentary.vim does not provide a visual mode mapping for a comment text object. Meaning you can not do `vgc`.