# How to comment a line in vim?

Tags: comments

```
#inlcude<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

I want to comment line where the cursor is. For, example if I am on the line `printf` then I want to get following -

```
#inlcude<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   /* printf("Hello world\n"); */
}
```

[keep in mind the comment style is `/* */`]

The command may be `:C` or `:Comment` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a key</kbd>

Comment: Commenting is a very common problem: [How to toggle comments with ctrl+/?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8128/778), [How to comment out a set of lines which are selected in visual mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/130/778), [Toggling comments on and off](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8160/778). I would recommend standing on the shoulders of giants and using a [comment plugin](https://vimawesome.com/?q=comment). I use [commentary.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way would be to map the keystrokes you would use to a key combination:

```
nnoremap gcc I/* <ESC>A */<ESC>
```

In normal mode, when pressing `gcc`, this will go to the beginning of the line and insert `/*` , then goes to the end of the line and insert  `*/`.

This might be already enough for you, but if you want more I would recommend just using a plugin for that, e.g. [Tim Pope's vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary).  Besides commenting C files, it also supports many other programming languages and uses the appropriate comment format for them.  You can define custom comment formats, and you can also uncomment lines (with the same combination `gcc`).

Comment: This works and I accepted this. Can you provide uncomment solution using `gcc`?

Comment: @alhelal sure, use the mentioned plugin ;)

Comment: And if you don't like vim-commentary for some reason, a couple of other popular commenting plugins you can try are [NERD Commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) and [TComment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim).