# Surround part of line with comment /* .. */

Tags: visual-mode, plugin-vim-surround

Is it possible to surround a selected part of a line with `/*` and `*/`?

```
start COMMENT ME end
start /*COMMENT ME*/ end
```

Comment: Kind of related [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/130/1841)

Comment: Though a dupe, tpope’s commentary and surround plugins solve cases like this very effectively

Comment: I don't want comment an entire row, i would comment only a part of that with /**/

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin name NerdCommenter provide many ways of commenting, includes `/*  */`: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter

If you just need a quick solution, here is the macro which does the trick:

**Update:**

`let @j="viws/*<esc>pa */<esc>"`

Let save it to your `.vimrc` file then using by moving the cursor at the word then `@j`.

Comment: I would comment only "foo bar"
123 foo barws/*  */<80>kl<80>kl<80>kl^[p 123

Comment: @MarcoAndreolli checkout the update, I'm using <esc> instead of weird character, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

The simple (redoable version, that messes `*` register) is

```
xnoremap µ s/* <c-r>" */<esc>
```

PS: this is quite certainly a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following sequences of keystrokes from visual mode to comment out the currently selected text:

```
c/**/<Esc>hP

c/*<C-R>"*/<Esc>
```

(Note that the second of these is essentially the same as in [Luc Hermitte's mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18170/343). See `:help i_CTRL-R` if you're not sure how it works.)